# How do I go about implementing a strange "class" notation

Tags: c++, uml

I'm writing an overengineered matrix calculator in C++ and don't know what this means:

[image]

I've never seen something like the box with Valuation = std::map in a class diagram before and don't really know what to look up either. Do i write it as a constructor or what? 
And why is there no connection between IntElement and Valuation even though IntElement Clearly uses it?

I have this in the header right now is it what the diagram is looking for?

```
class Valuation{

    Valuation(std::map<char,int>);

};
```

Comment: Looks like rubbish. Who produced that?

Comment: My advanced OOP professor. Probably.

Comment: By this I mean the oddball box with Valuation = std::map<char, int>. What is it supposed to be? A class? Why is it not presented the same way everything else is?

Comment: Go and ask him where he got that from. It is rubbish. No UML notation exists for that. It's a rectangle with text contained. Nothing else.

Comment: As a side note: that `n*n` label top right also looks very suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tough to say where this line would go without more context, but the `Valuation` box looks like it requests a line like:

```
using Valuation = std::map<char,int>;
```

That is, define `Valuation` as an alias for a certain map. Based on "reasonable" design, I'd expect this line to go in a common parent class of `VariableElement` and `IntElement`, possibly as a protected typedef. However, I see nothing in the diagram to suggest this.

I do not see enough context to guess why there is not a "uses" line from `IntElement` to `Valuation`. Both `IntElement` and `VariableElement` appear to be on equal footing regarding this, given the `evaluate` member. On the other hand, I would question why the existing line connects to `VariableElement` instead of to the hypothesized common parent that should define the alias. This might be something to bring up with the diagram's author. (Sometimes people make mistakes, even professors.)

*Addendum:* I had a thought about the difference between `IntElement::evaluate` and `VariableElement::evaluate`. It might be that the former ignores its parameter, hence it does not really use `Valuation` for more than the name of a type. On the other hand, the latter might look up an entry in the map, hence the implementation needs `Valuation` to be a complete type. It's a possible motivation, even though I find it questionable for such an implementation detail to affect a class diagram.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense. Thanks. They do share an interface further up the tree too.

Comment: Seems like it stays similarly disconnected in the further iterations of the diagram as well which is odd. (were creating the thing in weekly versions over months.)

Comment: @Stuge I had a thought and amended my answer. It might explain why `Valuation` stays disconnected. (It seems like a weak motivation to me, though.)

Comment: Where from do you draw that conclusion? Is there any specification that rectifies this? The above is just NO valid UML notation. Right? Down vote until you give a reference.

Comment: @qwerty_so I am not familiar with specifications that cover class diagrams. Mostly I'm working off of class names, function names, function signatures, and personal experience. I admit guesswork is not 100% certain; if you have better information, you are welcome to post your own answer.

Comment: @qwerty_so Hmm... it seems harsh to downvote an answer for not quoting a reference when the question does not ask for one. The question asks what the block means, not if the block is correct. Then again, it's also harsh to dismiss something as "rubbish" simply because you are unable to understand it. But do what you feel you should. I take it you are part of the crowd more interested in telling people how wrong they are than in working towards better answers?

Comment: Just add a comment at the beginning that you are just speculating about the authors intention and not going about justifying the use of that rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what the UML 2.5 spec says.

**9.2.4.1 Classifiers** *(p. 99)*

> The default notation for a Classifier is a solid-outline rectangle containing the Classifier’s name, and with compartments separated by horizontal lines below the name. The name of the Classifier should be centered in boldface. For those languages that distinguish between uppercase and lowercase characters, Classifier names should begin with an uppercase character.

I could not find any point in the UML spec that limits names to any given set of (unicode) characters. Maybe for the reason that you would need another book for that. So all we can take from the above is that

`Valuation = std::map<char,int>`

is an identifier in the same way as e.g.

`wiec8736b(/&& 3l?!blurb`

would be a (weird) identifier. But in no way it would be some operator clause where you can interpret the character `=` either as assignment or equality.

**tl;dr** This is rubbish. Go and ask the author what he meant. Tell him to use either a comment and understandable textual description or to stick to a valid UML notation.

---

As a side note: The author of that UML diagram uses a notation in the operations compartment which is not defined.

**9.6.4 Notation** *(p. 115)*

> If shown in a diagram, an Operation is shown as a text string of the form:
>
> ```
> [<visibility>] <name> ‘(‘ [<parameter-list>] ‘)’ 
>    [‘:’ [<return-type>] [‘[‘ <multiplicity-range> ‘]’] 
>    [‘{‘ <oper-property> [‘,’ <oper-property>]* ‘}’]]
> ```
>
> where:
>
> - `<visibility>` is the visibility of the Operation (see 7.4).
>
>   `<visibility> ::= ‘+’ | ‘-‘ | ‘#’ | ‘~’`

`/` is no defined visibility. Most likely the author took the freedom to use `//` as common for a comment. That's probably acceptable, but it does not render valid UML.

And as a 2nd side note: that `n*n` top right also looks suspicios. It's probably a multiplicity and in that format invalid as well. But that's just speculation.